# Error when changing column chart to 3D with Google Sheets API

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to change all column charts in my sheet into 3D column charts. When I run the code below, I receive an error stating that three dimensional column charts are not supported despite Google's documentation stating otherwise.

Is this a bug with the API? Or is there a problem with my code.

```
  function threeDCharts(){
     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheetID = sheet.getId();
  
     var charts = sheet.getSheetByName("Data").getCharts();

     var ids = [];
     var requests = [];

     for(i=0;i<charts.length;i++){
        ids.push(charts[i].getChartId())
     }
     for(i=0;i<charts.length;i++){
        requests.push({"updateChartSpec":{
           "chartId": ids[i],"spec":{
               "basicChart": {
                   "chartType": "column", "threeDimensional":true
                }
            }
         }});
     }

     var resp = Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests:requests}, sheetID);
  }
```

The verbatim error is as follows:

GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid requests[0].updateChartSpec: chartSpec.basicChart.threeDimensional not supported when chartSpec.basicChart.chartType is COLUMN.

The "threeDimensional" attribute in the link below shows that column charts should be supported.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts#BasicChartType

Edit for clarification:

Sample spreadsheet below.

Another function in my script will create a column chart of the row containing the averages, calculated by the spreadsheet, of the above individual measurements for each average. (In this case, two charts)

The function above I am having an the issue with will get a list of all charts in the sheet then use an updateChartSpec request to change the column charts to their "3D" format.

| **Measurment** | Sample A | Sample B | Sample C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mass 1 | 22 | 20 | 22 |
| Mass 2 | 22 | 20 | 22 |
| Mass 3 | 22 | 22 | 22 |
| Mass 4 | 22 | 22 | 20 |
| Mass 5 | 22 | 22 | 22 |
| **Average Mass** | 22.0 | 21.0 | 21.7 |
| Density 1 | 22.90 | 12.50 | 25.77 |
| Density 2 | 14.87 | 11.10 | 29.84 |
| Density 3 | 16.40 | 11.82 | 31.11 |
| Density 4 | 16.40 | 11.82 | 31.11 |
| Density 5 | 16.40 | 11.82 | 31.11 |
| **Average Density** | 17.4 | 11.8 | 29.8 |

[Want to go from the chart on the left to the chart on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GoaJ.png)

Comment: In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your current issue?

Comment: I have updated my post to be a little more clear, let me know if this is sufficient. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand your current charts from your updating question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: I added a link to an image showing the change to the chart I'd like the script to make. The chart on the left is created by a separate function and I'd like the script I am experiencing the issue with to change the chart on the left of the image to the chart on the right. From 2D to 3D.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your reply, I could understand your situation. When I tested it, I confirmed the same situation with you. And, when I checked this situation, I thought that this might be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

From your sample image, I could understand your situation.

When the column chart is manually set as 3D and retrieves the chart object using `Sheets.Spreadsheets.get` of Sheets API, I can confirm that `threeDimensional` is `true`.

But, when `threeDimensional` is `true` to the request body of `updateChartSpec` of the batchUpdate, an error like `chartSpec.basicChart.threeDimensional not supported when chartSpec.basicChart.chartType is COLUMN.` occurs.

In this case, even when `addChart` is used with `threeDimensional: true`, the same error occurs.

When `threeDimensional: true` is changed to `threeDimensional: false` for the same request body, no error occurs.

From this situation, I thought that in that case, that might be a bug in the current stage. So I would like to recommend reporting it to the Google issue tracker. https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker Because, when I searched about this, I couldn't find it.

#### References:

- [UpdateChartSpecRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatechartspecrequest)
- [AddChartRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#addchartrequest)

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming this for me! I will be sure to report the bug.

Comment: @Alex M Thank you for replying. I would like to believe that this bug will be resolved in the future update.

Comment: This is still broken. I just confirmed that the bug is still there.